# Decrease numeric input value when increasing another input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I should work with two input values that store only Integers when I increase the value of one, the other should decrease. This must stop if the second value hit 0.

The field that contains the value to be decreased is named with ID `form_val62_1`, and field that can be increased by the user input is called `form_val63_1`. I'm calling this function `onChange()` cause I need to pass the ID of the form (that's cause form fields are dynamically generated depending on a PHP array length).

```js
  function check(i) {
        $("#form_val63_" + i ).change(function () {
          var direction = this.defaultValue < this.value;
          this.defaultValue = this.value;
          var val;
          val = parseInt($("#form_val62_" + i).val());
          if (direction) {
            if (val > 0) {
              $('#form_val62_' + i).val(parseInt($(this).val()) - 1);
            } else {
              var thvar = $(this).val();
              $(this).val(thvar - 1);
            }
            console.log("increase 503");
            console.log(val);
          } else {
            $('#form_val62_' + i).val(parseInt($(this).val()) + 1);
            console.log("decrease 503");
            console.log(val);
          }
        });
      }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agrnzf3v/1/)

I got many problems here, the first decrease one time, that increase with no reason (I know there is but can't see why).

Using the solution provided by @Ph0b0x i've updated my code as

```
 var v = $("#form_val62_" + i).val(); //Let's say this is the value from PHP....
                var preVal = 0;

                $("#form_val62_" + i).val(v);

                $("#form_val63_" + i).on("change keyup keydown", function(event) {
                    let currVal = parseInt($("#form_val63_" + i).val());

                    console.log(preVal);
                    console.log(currVal);

                    if (currVal == 0) {
                        preVal = 0;
                        $("#form_val62_" + i).val(v);
                    } else if (currVal <= v) {
                        $("#form_val62_" + i).val((v - currVal) == 0 ? 0 : (v - currVal));
                        preVal = currVal;
                    } else {
                        $("#form_val63_" + i).val(v);
                    }

                });
```

Now I can increase the result but when i try decrease the each value remain 0.

Comment: you do not bind the change to BOTH elements.... That seems like an issue.

Comment: So the maximum value is the start value right?

Comment: Where is "i" defined and why is there any particular reason the selector should be like that? Also, are you checking the browser's console to see if there's any errors?

Comment: `i` is defined in the input such as every input is generated as a collection. so like `<input class="form-control" type="number" value="0" min="0" id="form_val63_{{ item }}" onchange="check({{ item }})">` where `item` is an id.

Comment: The value is provided by an AJAX function on load then populate the array of inputs.

Comment: Understood, in my fiddle i am able to increase and decrease the value. Here's an updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/Ph0b0x/agrnzf3v/27/ 
Probably check the console to see if there's any errors?

Comment: It's working! thanks! If you update your reply i will mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

I guess, if i understood correctly, i will keep track of the previous value on the second input then i will start decreasing the first one until it reaches 0 and increase it until it reaches 10? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ph0b0x/agrnzf3v/18/)

HTML

```
<form>
  <input id="form_val62_1" type="number" min="0" value="10" />
  <input id="form_val63_1" type="number" min="0" value="0" />
</form>
```

JS

```
var v = 13; //Let's say this is the value from PHP....
var preVal = 0;

$("#form_val62_1").val(v);

$("#form_val63_1").on("change keyup keydown", function(event) {
  let currVal = parseInt($("#form_val63_1").val());

  console.log(preVal);
  console.log(currVal);

  if (currVal == 0) {
    preVal = 0;
    $("#form_val62_1").val(v);
  } else if (currVal <= v) {
    $("#form_val62_1").val((v - currVal) == 0 ? 0 : (v - currVal));
    preVal = currVal;
  } else {
    $("#form_val63_1").val(v);
  }

});
```

Edit: I have updated my code based on your comment. Please see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ph0b0x/agrnzf3v/24/)

Comment: it seems I have explained myself badly. The value in the first field is variable, it is generated by PHP (it is not 10). As the value in the second field increases, the one in the first must go down. As the value decreases in the second field, the one in the first must rise. The value of the first field can not fall below 0 and in that case the value of the second field can not increase but only decrease.

Comment: By this "The value of the first field can not fall below 0 and in that case the value of the second field can not increase but only decrease" you mean that it cannot got higher that's its initial value set by PHP?

Answer (score 0):

So bind change event handlers on both elements. I would just use data attributes so you do not have to worry about selecting by ids to bind between both.

```js
$('[data-num-grp]').on('input', function () {
  // input that was interacted with
  const inp1 = $(this);
  // get the group number
  const grp = inp1.data('num-grp')
  // select the other element with the grp
  const inp2 = $('[data-num-grp="' + grp + '"]').not(inp1);
  // alter the other element so it's value changes
  inp2.val(this.max - this.value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" data-num-grp="1" min="0" max="10" value="10"/>
<input type="number" data-num-grp="1" min="0" max="10" value="0"/>
<br/>
<input type="number" data-num-grp="2" min="0" max="10" value="10"/>
<input type="number" data-num-grp="2" min="0" max="10" value="0"/>
```